# How could i make sure the sole is constantly moving, not bouncing?

Tags: drivers

There is a tank whose tank track movement is given by a Cylinder that has *Rigid Body* physics, but the tank track bounces. How fix this? (I made the movement of the tank track with the help of a Driver.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "bouncing"?

Answer (score 0):

Blender uses quaternions in simulations, then they are converted into Euler angles then using drivers. So that you have only one turn in animation, because there is no way to get information how much turns object has done from  quaternions.

If instead you will use regular animation and get transform channel as driver input, you will get what you want:

[image]